# Angular lazy loaded module navgation to child problem

Tags: angular

I'm creating a admin and user app in Angular 6 and so far I have two lazy loaded modules UserModule and AdminModule. My app main routing looks like

```
const routes: Routes =
[
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'user',    loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'},
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'page-not-found'},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My user modules contains only user.module and user-routing.module inside the module there are multi-component it looks like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: IndexComponent },
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      {path: 'Register', component: RegistrationComponent },

    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

One of them is the main page with `<app-login></app-login>` with main navbar with URL when I try to navigate to nay URL I got error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /user/login

My menu is

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" routerLink="Register" routerLinkActive='active'>Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" routerLink='login' routerLinkActive='active'>login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where is the error in navigate to children pages?

Comment: Did you place router-outlet in IndexComponent html?

Comment: Yes and opened inside the page but I wanna it to open as a new page

Comment: in this example, you don't use the lazy loading principe

Answer (score 0):

You need review routing structure because each route level needs it own router-outlet

Here working example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-child-routing)

And in module routing HomeRoutingModule you need delete empty sublevel

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexComponent,
    children: [
      // {path: '', component: IndexComponent },
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      {path: 'Register', component: RegistrationComponent },

    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: even the example din't work in need each one open in separated page where I have routerout let in app component.ts

Comment: @mr.alaa if you click on 'login' link it will show index and login text, also look into internal console it will show navigation trace NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/user/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/user/login"}

Comment: it sill not showing login in as anew page there should be router outlet to be shown in the same page while I need it in separated with another full design that's why I separate it

Comment: if you want separate login page you should move login to dedicated module and change route accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my app structure and now works perfectly  thanks to all